# Derivative of function of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-calculus

I need help to take a derivative wrt a matrix, I'll much appreciate any help.

Suppose $X \in R^{m\times n}$ and $a,b \in R^{m \times 1}$. Let function $f$ be 
\begin{equation}
f(X)=(a^T X X^Tb -c)^2
\end{equation}
where $c$ is a scalar constant. What is $\partial f / \partial X = ?$

My second question is more complex.

Assume the function $f$ now be

\begin{equation}
f(X)=(g(X^Ta)^T g(X^Tb) -c)^2
\end{equation}

where $g : R^{n\times 1} \rightarrow R ^{n \times 1}$ is a differentiable function. Again what is $\partial f / \partial X = ?$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me try to answer your second question, since no one else has.

First, I'll assume that your $g$ function is a scalar function applied elementwise, since the result has the same shape as the argument.

I'll also assume that this scalar function has a known derivative 
$$
g^\prime(s) = \frac {dg(s)} {ds}
$$
Next, I'll generalize from the vector arguments in your question, to matrix arguments, and define the symbols 
$$ \eqalign {
  g_A &= g(X^T\cdot A) \cr
  g_B &= g(X^T\cdot B) \cr
  h &= g_A:g_B - c \cr
} $$
Finally, let's denote the Frobenius and Hadamard product between matrices $A,B$ as 
$(A:B)$ and $(A\circ B)$ respectively.

Now it's just a matter of taking the differential and expanding
$$ \eqalign {
 df &= dh^2 \cr
    &= 2 h (dh) \cr
    &= 2 h (g_B:dg_A + g_A:dg_B) \cr
    &= 2 h (g_B:g^\prime_A\circ d(X^T\cdot A) + g_A:g^\prime_B\circ d(X^T\cdot B)) \cr
    &= 2 h (g_B\circ g^\prime_A:d(X^T\cdot A) + g_A\circ g^\prime_B:d(X^T\cdot B)) \cr
    &= 2 h (g_B\circ g^\prime_A\cdot A^T:dX^T + g_A\circ g^\prime_B\cdot B^T:dX^T) \cr
    &= 2 h (g_B\circ g^\prime_A\cdot A^T + g_A\circ g^\prime_B\cdot B^T) : dX^T \cr
    &= 2 h (g_B\circ g^\prime_A\cdot A^T + g_A\circ g^\prime_B\cdot B^T)^T : dX \cr
} $$
So the derivative is
$$ \eqalign {
 \frac {\partial f} {\partial X} &= 2 h (g_B\circ g^\prime_A\cdot A^T + g_A\circ g^\prime_B\cdot B^T)^T  \cr
   &= 2 h A\cdot(g_B\circ g_A^{\prime})^T + 2 h B\cdot(g_A\circ g_B^{\prime})^T  \cr
} $$
Your first question uses the identity function, $g(s) = s$, whose derivative is $g^\prime(s) = 1$.

Since a matrix of all ones acts as the identity for the Hadamard product, the derivative reduces to
$$ \eqalign {
 \frac {\partial f} {\partial X} &= 2 h A\cdot(g_B)^T + 2 h B\cdot(g_A)^T  \cr
   &= 2 h A\cdot(X^T\cdot B)^T + 2 h B\cdot(X^T\cdot A)^T  \cr
   &= 2 h A\cdot B^T\cdot X + 2 h B\cdot A^T\cdot X  \cr
} $$

Answer (score 1):

Apparently what we are looking for is a differential $Df(X) : \mathbb R^{
m\times n}\to \mathbb R$, which DOES exist, as $f$ is $C^\infty$, and it is realized by the matrix $G=(g_{ij})\in\mathbb R^{m\times n}$, where
$$
g_{ij}=\frac{\partial F}{\partial X_{ij}}.
$$
Now
$$
F(X)=\left(\sum_{i,j,k=1}^n a_iX_{ik}X_{jk}b_j-c\right)^2,
$$
and hence
$$
\frac{\partial F}{\partial X_{rs}}=2\left(\sum_{i,j,k=1}^n a_iX_{ik}X_{jk}b_j-c\right)\,\left(\sum_{j=1}^n a_rX_{js}b_j+\sum_{i=1}^n a_iX_{is}b_r\right) \\=
2\left(\sum_{i,j,k=1}^n a_iX_{ik}X_{jk}b_j-c\right)\,\left(a_r(X^Tb)_s+b_r(a^TX)_s\right),
$$
and finally
$$
G=2(a^TXX^Tb-c)\,\big(a(b^TX)+b(a^TX)\big).
$$

Comment: Thanks! I'm just curios what is $\partial a^T X X^T b / \partial X= ?$.

Comment: Answer. $a(b^TX)+b(a^TX)$.

Comment: Wrong indeed.  $ab'X$ is an outer product of two vectors which always exists and has dimension $m\times n$ in your example.

Comment: Sorry, I've misread it :D Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Just take the derivative with respect to each element separately and stick them into a matrix.

For instance, if $e_i$ is the $i$--th unit vector then the derivative of $f$ with respect to $X_{ij}$ is

$$2e_i'(ba'X + ab'X) e_j (a'XX'b-c)$$.

So you're right, although it depends on your notation style whether you take the matrix you mention or its transpose as the derivative.

As an aside, it can be preferable to first vectorize a matrix before taking derivatives, especially if higher order derivatives are desired.